# forward websocket to websocket

Tags: nginx, websocket

I'm using the nginx as reverse proxy for django and React with as config

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http{
    server{
        include mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        keepalive_timeout  240;
        sendfile on;
        listen 8001;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        location /{
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location /backend {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }   
 }
}
```

its working fine but i want to forward websocket for react hot loading.  i have still no solution after lot of googling. currently it have connection error as from chrome console

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8001/sockjs-node' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of http directive, i  that thought it will not support forward WebSocket proxy but after more spending time on google. i known that http is upgrade to Websocket after initial handshake So finally the solution is here

its worked for me as forward proxy for Django as backend and react as frontend. so i can pass CORS problem due to server are at different IP and its unsecure so setting header not support much regard cookie sharing

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http{
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    server{
        include mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        keepalive_timeout  240;
        sendfile on;
        listen 8001;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        location /{
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location /backend {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }   
        location /sockjs-node {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
 }
}
```